# Create JOIN query between multiple tables dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
id    int,
name  varchar(50),

PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

insert into t1 (id,name) values(1,'t1.1')
insert into t1 (id,name) values(2,'t1.2')
insert into t1 (id,name) values(3,'t1.3')

CREATE TABLE t2 (
  id    int,
  name  varchar(50),

  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_t1_t2 FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES t1(Id)
);

insert into t2 (id,name) values(1,'t2.1')
insert into t2 (id,name) values(2,'t2.2')
insert into t2 (id,name) values(3,'t2.3')



-- SQL created manualy:
select * from t1
join t2 on t2.id = t1.id


drop table t2
drop table t1
```

This is a very simple example. Think about a giant database structure with a lot of foreign key references!

It's a hard job to define all the join-conditions correct manually!

I would like to create this SQL statement dynamically!

The foreign references are already defined in the database, but where?

The script should give this out:

```
  select 
    t1.id,
    t1.name,
    t2.id,
    it2.name
  from t1
  join t2 on t2.id = t1.id
```

Someone has already solved the problem?

addendum: The Parameters to the script are the first Tablename and the last Tablename. Those two tables should be connected together with all their relevant inter- or reference-tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the trick, but I would not advise to do it like this.

Issues: Referencing the same table more often (Aliasing), type of joining (inner, left, ...), selected column list...

```
DECLARE @table AS VARCHAR(100)='YouTableName';

WITH AllColumns AS
(
    SELECT pObj.name AS ParentTable  
          ,pCol.COLUMN_NAME AS ParentColumn
          ,fkObj.name AS ReferecedTable 
          ,fkCol.COLUMN_NAME AS ReferencedColumn

    FROM sys.foreign_key_columns AS fkc 
    INNER JOIN sys.objects AS pObj ON pObj.object_id=fkc.parent_object_id
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS pCol ON pCol.TABLE_NAME=pObj.name AND pCol.ORDINAL_POSITION=fkc.parent_column_id 
    INNER JOIN sys.objects AS fkObj ON fkObj.object_id=fkc.referenced_object_id
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS fkCol ON fkCol.TABLE_NAME=fkObj.name AND fkCol.ORDINAL_POSITION=fkc.referenced_column_id 
    WHERE fkc.constraint_object_id IN 
    (
        SELECT object_id FROM sys.objects AS o
        WHERE o.name IN
        (
            SELECT tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS tc
            WHERE tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE='FOREIGN KEY'
              AND tc.TABLE_NAME=@table
        )
    )
)
SELECT 'SELECT *
        FROM ' + @table +
        (
            SELECT ' INNER JOIN ' + ac.ReferecedTable + ' ON ' + ac.ParentTable + '.' + ac.ParentColumn + '=' + ac.ReferecedTable + '.' + ac.ReferencedColumn + CHAR(10) 
            FROM AllColumns AS ac
            FOR XML PATH('')
        )
```

Comment: Hi Shnugo, your abilities are absolutely stunning. When I grow up I will just become like you! ^^ Thank you (again!)!

Comment: The background of my question is: a database structure is nothing else but a network of data. I have an enter-point and an exit-point of data. e.g. I know the customer name and the article name. I don't know nothing about the structures of the database and I need not to know about it. The stored procedure shall search all the relevant table connections an build me up a runnable script. Who knows how the relation is bound between customers and the articles in future? Changes in structure implies changes in the code and these changes are the hotbed for bugs.

Comment: @NECIPS, sounds great - but I'm afraid it is an even hotter bed :-) If your code does not know what to expect from a call it will need a lot of dirty and generic programming. I think you should better define actual UDFs or SPs doing a defined job and deliver a defined result. The code "doing everything with any strcuture to deliver something" is - in most cases - not the best idea... Good luck, happy coding and merry X-mas

Comment: I'll follow your advice and keep my mind open for ideas. ^^ merry X-mas!

Answer (score 0):

Awesome script from [Shnugo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5089204/shnugo). But it has some drawbacks:

1. It does not work for custom schemes - only for tables in default
   `dbo` schema
2. It does not work for tables with Unicode symbols or spaces
3. It doe not `PRINT` statement with *nice* formatting options

I improve this script to solve this issues:

```sql
    /*
    <documentation>
      <summary>Create JOIN query between multiple tables dynamically.</summary>
      <returns>SELECT statement from input table with INNER JOINS for all tables having foreign consttraints with input table.</returns>
      <issues>Does not properly generate alias for case with multiply foreign keys for one table</issues>
      <author>Konstantin Taranov</author>
      <created>2019-04-22</created>
      <modified>2019-04-23 by Konstantin Taranov</modified>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <sourceLink>https://github.com/ktaranov/sqlserver-kit/blob/master/Scripts/Create_JOIN_Query_Between_Multiple_Tables_Dynamically.sql</sourceLink>
    </documentation>
    */

    DECLARE @schemaName    AS sysname       = N'dbo';
    DECLARE @tableName     AS sysname       = N'TableName';
    DECLARE @tableFullName AS nvarchar(256) = QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName)
    DECLARE @crlf          AS varchar(10)   = CHAR(10);
    DECLARE @tsql          AS nvarchar(max);

    IF LEFT(@tableName, 1) = N'[' OR LEFT(@schemaName, 1) = N'['
    THROW 50001, 'Please do not use quotes in Table or Schema names! In the script it is alredy done with QUOTENAME function.', 1;

    IF OBJECT_ID(@tableFullName) IS NULL
    THROW 50002, 'Table is not exist in database. Please check @schemaName and @tableName variables.', 1;


    WITH AllColumns
         AS (SELECT
                    pObj.name                    AS ParentTable
                   ,pCol.COLUMN_NAME             AS ParentColumn
                   ,SCHEMA_NAME(fkObj.schema_id) AS ReferecedTableSchema
                   ,fkObj.name                   AS ReferecedTable
                   ,fkCol.COLUMN_NAME            AS ReferencedColumn
             FROM sys.foreign_key_columns AS fkc
                  INNER JOIN sys.objects  AS pObj ON pObj.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
                  INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS pCol ON pCol.TABLE_NAME = pObj.name
                                                                   AND pCol.ORDINAL_POSITION = fkc.parent_column_id
                  INNER JOIN sys.objects AS fkObj ON fkObj.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
                  INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS fkCol ON fkCol.TABLE_NAME = fkObj.name
                                                                    AND fkCol.ORDINAL_POSITION = fkc.referenced_column_id
             WHERE fkc.constraint_object_id IN
             (
                 SELECT
                        object_id
                 FROM sys.objects AS o
                 WHERE o.name IN
                 (
                     SELECT
                            tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME AS CONSTRAINT_NAME
                     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS tc
                     WHERE tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
                       AND tc.TABLE_NAME   = @tableName
                       AND tc.TABLE_SCHEMA = @schemaName
                 )
             ))
         SELECT 
                @tsql = 
               N'SELECT TOP(100) ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + N'.*' + @crlf +
               N'FROM ' + @tableFullName +
         ISNULL(
         (
             SELECT
                    @crlf +  N'INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(ac.ReferecedTableSchema) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(ac.ReferecedTable) + N' ON' + @crlf +
                    N'           ' + QUOTENAME(ac.ParentTable) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(ac.ParentColumn) + ' = ' +
                    QUOTENAME(ac.ReferecedTable) + '.' + QUOTENAME(ac.ReferencedColumn)
             FROM AllColumns AS ac FOR
             XML PATH('')
         ), N'') + N';';

    IF @tsql IS NULL
    PRINT('@tsql is NULL - something went wrong!');
    ELSE
    PRINT(@tsql);
```